# How to provide an array in getStaticPaths?

Tags: next.js

I learn nextJS and I try to use dynamic routes with a catch-all route. However I'm running into a basic problem, I'm not sure how to supply the data as an array in getStaticPaths.

This is my current code:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';

function test({ variable }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>{variable.var}</h1>

        <Link href="/">
          <a>← Back</a>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const variable = params.variable;
  return {
    props: {
      variable,
    },
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    fallback: false,
    paths: [
      {
        params: {
          variable: 'testi',
        },
      },
    ],
  };
}

export default test
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
Error: A required parameter (variable) was not provided as an array in getStaticPaths for /test/[...variable]
```

Any ideas?

Edit:
Forgot to add, my current file name is [...variable].js

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed it was stupid:

```
 paths: [
            { params: { variable: ["testi"] } },
        ]
```